# Feeds import multilanguage CSV into Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, feed, drupal-feeds

I have a CSV file which contains information about products in different languages and I'm trying to import them as nodes into my Drupal 7 installation using the Feeds module.

The problem is that I want to be able to map certain columns of the CSV with a certain language so when it creates the node it makes an English node with Name_en,Desc_en,etc... and a Dutch node with Name_nl, Info_nl and so on. Apparently this functionality is not supported by Feeds at the moment, any idea on how can achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: str_getcsv, node_object_prepare, and node_save

Comment: I dont think Feeds supports this, you probably need to do it directly in the database

Comment: This discussion on drupal.org was helpful for me: http://drupal.org/node/997858

Comment: In case anybody is searching for a solution, there seems to be a module for feeds that does just that: https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_et I haven't tested it, though.